# Overflow-x is not scrollable in my case

Tags: scrollbar, overflow

Overflow-x is not scrollable in my case. Please see the result in the picture.  It just shows the scrollbar but it's not scrollable.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utz9Q.png)

Here's what I've done

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
<table class="table">
....
</table>
</div>

.table-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden; 
}
```

I've searched on the internet and tried some other instructions but don't work for me.

Comment: Attempt to recreate the result in JSFiddle, or an equivalent. Then post that recreation so that we may have more information.

Comment: I do this in Visual composer. Do you think this may be the cause?

Comment: I wouldn't know. the code you posted here works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/noehesmr/

Comment: Yeah, It works there. But it doesn't work in my Wordpress site. I use a page creator plugin. I insert a raw html and add css in the plugin. It's not working. So confused.

Comment: Other css rules work well, except for overflow-x:scroll.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you have to define max-width max-height (max-height: 410px !important;) of your table once data will be overflow in table row it will we display scroller.